# Laravel 4.1.* AJAX response method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to setup a simple POST method with AJAX, posting to a Laravel controller and processed.

The issue I am having is returning a response that the AJAX call understand and can use.

**routes.php**

```
Route::controller('supply-us/application', 'ApplicationController');
Route::post('supply-us/application', 'ApplicationController@processSupplierApplication');
```

AJAX stuff to get form data:

```
   $('#supplierChainCheckForm').submit(function( event ) {
     event.preventDefault();

     function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
         return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
     }

     // As we're using the "csfrUnsafeMethod" of POST - we'll need to setup the csfr token to be passed between client and server:
     $.ajaxSetup({
         // This is standard before send method for the ajaxSetup() function:
         beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
             // If settings.type in $.ajax method is unsafe i.e., if it is 'POST' then we'll need to set X-CSRFToken in the xhr Request Header: omitted && sameOrigin(settings.url) currently;
             if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type)) {
                 xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));
             }
         }
     });

     // Get all the form inputs into an array:
     var $inputs = $('#supplierChainCheckForm :input');
     // We can now loop over all of the input names & values of the form:
     var values = {};
     $inputs.each(function() {
         values[this.name] = $(this).val();
     });

     $.ajax({
       type: 'POST', //This will always be a post method for the supplier chain check form.
       url: 'supply-us/application', //URL endpoint for the post form method: we'll set this to the controller function we're targeting.
       data: { 'companyName': values['companyName'] ,'_token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'}
     }).done(function(response) {
       console.log(response.companyName);
     });
   });
```

**ApplicationController.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

class ApplicationController extends FrontController {

  public function getSupplierApplication() {
         return self::getPage('supply-us/application');
    }

  public function processSupplierApplication() {

    if (!Input::get('companyName') == null) {
      $company = Input::get('companyName');

      return Response::json([ 'companyName' => $company ], 200);
    } else {
      $company = "No compnay specified";

      return Response::json([ 'companyName' => $company ], 200);

    }
  }
}
```

However, combining all of the above gives me

`console.log(response.companyName)` as "*undefined*"

Please advise. Please note, I am using **Laravel 4.1.***

Comment: @Tschallacka Enlightening - and what *should* I be using?

Comment: `Input::get` is what you want to use. It has nothing to do with the type of request, just that you are getting the field from the Input. If you use `console.log(response)`, what do you get? If you get the json string, then you need to decode it in your javascript before you can get the properties.

Comment: The part of your post being removed by users with the ability to remove it is being removed for a reason. It can be seen as very passive-aggressive and also as fluff by the community. It is not needed for the question, it is not needed on StackOverflow.

Comment: @aynber This essentially returns html ... of the page I'm posting to. Minus a lot. Seems to be just the header and footer?

Comment: Interesting that it's giving you html instead of the actual response. That means it's throwing some sort of error. Try adding a slash to the beginning of your ajax URL, so it doesn't get change by being in a "subdirectory". Check your logs in `app/storage/logs` to see if there's anything being thrown there, and check the headers in the network tab of your developer console to make sure it's not returning a 404 or 500.

Comment: @aynber No console errors, and I have debug on - no errors logged either there. The response coming back now is { "companyName": "My Company" } so do I need to do something with what I'm passing in to my variables?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts stop adding commentary to your question. It serves no purpose. This post will unlock after an hour. I don't expect to see it edited again.

Answer (score 0):

Update function parameter as below;

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class ApplicationController extends FrontController {

  public function getSupplierApplication() {
         return self::getPage('supply-us/application');
    }

  public function processSupplierApplication(Request $request) {

    if (!$request->input('companyName') == null) {
      $company = $request->input('companyName');

      return Response::json([ 'companyName' => $company ], 200);
    } else {
      $company = "No compnay specified";

      return Response::json([ 'companyName' => $company ], 200);

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Argument 1 passed to ApplicationController::processSupplierApplication() must be an instance of Illuminate\Http\Request, none given